# Using Cell Tags and objectForKey in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I'm converting my project from `Objective-C` to `Swift`, and trying to figure how to write this in `Swift`:

```
UILabel *tvLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:104];
tvLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"tv"];
```

I've tried a few things different things like this:

```
    if let tvLabel = object?["tv"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = cell.viewWithTag(4) as? UILabel
    }
```

... but they all have errors and I can't seem to get the solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
if let tvLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as? UILabel {
    tvLabel.text = object.objectForKey("tv") as! String
}
```

Safer way:

```
if let tvLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as? UILabel, let tvString = object?.objectForKey("tv") as? String {
    tvLabel.text = tvString
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that looks closer to what I need, but I'm still getting an error `Cannot subscript a value of type PFObject`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my response, it wasn't an actual translation of your objective-c code before

Comment: If I use the updated response, it errors and asks me to use a `!` or `?`, and when I do that it gives me an error `Cannot assign a value of type AnyObject? to a value of type String?`  Do you know why that would be?

Comment: updated the answer again, added `as! String`. It's not certain what kind of object will be returned from `objectForKey("tv")`, if there's anything returned at all. So it returns `AnyObject?`(nil or AnyObject). You have to cast that to a `String` if you want to use it as one. I've also added a cleaner way in my answer, `as! String` could crash your app if the cast fails while `as? String` will allow the cast to fail

Comment: The Safer way gives an error `Value of optional type PFObject not unwrapped; did you mean to use ? or !`?

Comment: Would you use a `!` in `object!.objectForKey` then?

Comment: whoops! I would do `object?.objectForKey`. Just in case `object` is nil or whatever.. `?` is safer :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!